# Meaning of Spiritus Lenis

Tags: grammar-choice, terminology

I'm studying Arabic grammar from an old text book and it uses the term Spiritus Lenis. What does it mean?

To quote the book:

> The object of it is merely to distinguish elif as the long vowel (ie lam-elif) from the elif as the spiritus lenis (elif with hamza)

Comment: I, for one, would be very interested in knowing more about the specific context in which your book is using the term _spiritus lenis_. Can you update your original question to provide more details? Perhaps quote the sentence that includes the term?

Comment: @cnread I've quoted the specific passage of the book.

Comment: @Mikail: Thanks for updating the question. But what does 'it' in the quoted sentence refer to? hamza?

Comment: @cnread it refers to lam-elif.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Smooth breathing." When a word in ancient Greek began with a vowel, ancient scholars gave it one of two breathing marks. The *spiritus lenis* (Gk. ψιλὸν πνεῦμα) meant it was not aspirated, while the rough breathing (Lt. *spiritus asper*, Gk. δασὺ πνεῦμα) meant it should be aspirated.

Comment: I see what you're saying but, although I'm hardly an expert in Arabic, I don't believe it's quite correct, technically. My grammars are emphatic that no Arabic word begins with a vowel. A word such as the definite article ال that seems to us to begin with a vowel really begins with hamza, which is the initial consonant and, in formal writing, has a vowel sign (fatḥah, in the case of the definite article) to indicate the vowel sound. Initial alif in these cases merely carries the hamza (which is then followed by the vowel indicated by the vowel sign) and has no actual pronunciation of its own.

Comment: (continued) (Of course, in writing, the definite article isn't typically written with either hamza or fatḥah, which makes it seem as though the word begins with alif.) Maybe change 'when a vowel begins a word' to 'when a vowel sound seems to begin a word' or the like?

Comment: @cnread I'll just remove it. I do not know Arabic, so I'm not confident in making accurate changes. Maybe someone who actually knows Arabic can chime in.

Comment: @cnread: My impression is that it depends on what you mean by "begins with a vowel". Whenever someone pronounces a vowel, obviously it has to start with some kind of phonetic transition from the previous sound. This phonetic transition may or may not be identified with a consonant phoneme depending on the language. For example, in standard German, all words that start with a vowel letter in writing are pronounced with a "[glottal stop](http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/general/Dissertations/Garellek_dissertation.pdf)" or "hard attack", but this is usually not listed as a consonant of German.

Comment: @cnread: I'm not an expert about Arabic, but my impression is that the definite article will be pronounced with a glottal stop after a pause, but not if it comes after another vowel in the same spoken phrase (which is why e.g. "عبد ال‎‎" is generally transcribed in English as "Abdul", not "Abdu'l"). Wikipedia talks about a distinction between "[hamzat waṣl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamza#Hamzat_wa.E1.B9.A3l)" and "hamzat qaṭ‘".

Comment: @sumelic Can you weigh in on what I removed from my answer?

Comment: @sumelic. Yes, there are two varieties of hamza, and a sort of ellision occurs _in pronunciation_ when the previous word ends in a vowel. But, technically speaking, the article still starts with hamza, which is a consonant (in this case, written as a sort of sideways teardrop shape). It's not really the same at all, but think of the ellision that occurs in the Latin phrase _locum amoenum_. We wouldn't say that the form _locum_ ends in 'c' just because the _um_ isn't pronounced in poetry.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I agree with your answer. The elif with the hamza is pronounced with a short sound without any exhalation of air.